# OleDbCommand Select Convert["Column"] From Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Do you guys know how to convert on oledbcommand select statement? Below is what I'm trying to do, but I'm still getting error. I'm using it for my bulkcopy.ColumnsMappings.Add to bulkcopy.WritetoServer(ExcelDataRow) on my database on sql.

```
// Simple Example of what I'm trying to do...
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand("select Convert[Order Number] as decimal(17,7) as Order_Number from [" + ddlSheetName + "]", connExcel);

    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[Order Number]", "ORDER_NUM");
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(ExcelDataRow);
```

Comment: `Convert[Order Number] as decimal(17,7)` is missing `()` and seems a mix of `CAST/CONVERT` syntax from T-SQL which is unrelated to the Excel driver.  There is `CDec([Order Number])` for a decimal but I think your best bet is to return it as is (or as a string with `cstr()`) then re-cast in C# as needed.

Comment: Is it okay... if you post the example syntax of that approach as a whole in applying it on my example code above? Thank you...

Comment: Excel engine is not supporting `Convert()` use somthing like that: `"select Order Number as Order_Number from [" + ddlSheetName + "$]"`, load this query to `DataTable` and make the conversion from your app using C# .